# LLVM IR less or equal compare with negation

Tags: x86, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to make compare less or equal operation with two integers: op1 <= -op2. But both operands can be minimal values (0x80...0), so 'neg' can produce poison values. If I used x86 asm, I would write:

```
add r8,r9
jle SOME_LABEL
```

But in LLVM IR I can only write following construction:

```
%neg_op2 = sub i64 0, %op2
%cmp_sle = icmp sle i64 %op1, %neg_op2
```

which will not work if op2 = MIN_VALUE. Of course I can add additional comparisons, but resulting x86 code would be much worse than add+jle. And precious performance will be lost.

Is there any way to make LLVM perform the same operation by the cost of  add+jle? My target platform is x86, so I can sacrifice platform-independent features.

Comment: Have you tried writing it in 'C' than using clang to emit the LLVM-IR to see what it does? Did you run the LLVM-IR through `opt` or any other tool to see how it may improve what you've posted?

Comment: The code I posted is not correct - so there is nothing to improve. I used opt + llc to check some scenarios like getting manually overflow flags from add_with_carry/uadd_with_overflow intrinsics, using 128-bit operands, but I got unsatisfiable result.

Comment: There is no poison value. That only happens if you mark the `sub` with `nsw` (or `nuw`) but you didn't (and shouldn't).

Comment: Right, but it does not help to solve the source problem :)